# How to display different date for each item added to a list?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to React, so please bare with me. I'd like to display the date and time of each item (the date when it was added to the list) I'm adding to the list. Can't seem to make it work with what I already have. I'd really appreciate if someone could give me an explanation on how this could be achieved.

```
  const [notesList, setNotesList] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState<string>("");
  
  const wrapperRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useClickOutside(wrapperRef, () => setShowSidePanel(false));
  
  const addNote = (): void => {
    setNotesList([...notesList, ""]);
  };


  const deleteNote = React.useCallback(
    (idx: number): void => {
      const newList = [...notesList];
      newList.splice(idx, 1);
      setNotesList(newList);
    },
    [notesList]
  );

  const updateNote = React.useCallback(
    (idx: number, text: string): void => {
      const newList = [...notesList];
      newList.splice(idx, 1, text);
      setNotesList(newList);
    },
    [notesList]
  );

  const getFilteredNotes = (notes: string[], query: string,) => {
    if (!query) {
      return notes;
    }
    return notes.filter((note) => note.includes(query));
  };

  const filteredNotes = getFilteredNotes(notesList, query);
  const updateQuery = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  const handleSearch = debounce(updateQuery, 500);

  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <SidePanel showSidePanel={showSidePanel}>
        <HeaderContainer>
          <SearchInput
            placeholder="Search notes"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleSearch}
          />
          <Button variant="icon" onClick={addNote}>
            <AddIcon />
          </Button>
        </HeaderContainer>
        {notesList.length > 0 &&
          (filteredNotes && filteredNotes.length > 0 ? (
            filteredNotes.map((note: string, idx: number) => (
              <Note
                onChange={updateNote}
                remove={deleteNote}
                idx={idx}
                text={note}
                date={new Date()}
                key={idx}
              />
            ))
          ) : (
            <Text>No results found</Text>
          ))}
      </SidePanel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Now you're just creating the current date, so it will print the same day everytime, you must have the date value in some place first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way React works in general, it re-renders the component when the state is updated. When you add a new note it doesn't just append new element, it redraws the whole thing. Therefore, {new Date()}, will always show you the time of the last render in every element.

What you need to do, is to store the each date in app state, along with the note's text. Instead of a string array, you could store an array of objects like

```
{text: string, date: Date}
```

The date should be set in the 'addNote()' method, and {note.date} would be used while rendering.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is there any way to keep the string array and add the date another way?

Comment: I guess you could keep a separate date array or something like that, but that seems a bit messy. It makes more sense to me, to keep related data together.
The bottom line is,  you need to store it somewhere and the rendering code is no place for it.